# Using a PeoplePicker in an update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012

How can I correct the design window when using a peoplepicker?

When trying to add a peoplepicker I get a happy control and page:(background to picker added for visibility)
[image]

When trying to move that peoplepicker inside the update panel I get an error rendering the page. I have some controls added to make sure they show up. 
[image]

Interestingly running the page as is will result in a working page at runtime. But design side is completely unusable. I would really like to avoid moving the control out of the updatepanel to work and then remember to put it back to deploy.

Environment: VS2012, SQL2012, windows 2012, hosting SP2013.

Comment: Design View in VS doesn't have access to the SharePoint object you're using. In most cases Design View only shows asp.NET objects, since it's not a SharePoint tool. You might want to try using the designer?

Comment: But it does show up when placed outside of the updatepanel. This is the orange rectangle in the first screenshot.

Comment: The people picker also uses AJAX, so it's possible that conflicts with the UpdatePanel, but then it's weird that it's working okay at runtime. Are you using a SafeScriptManager (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee413872.aspx)?

Comment: The only ScriptManager is on the masterpage.

Comment: The SafeScriptManager is basically a ScriptManager with SharePoint-specific UpdatePanel-specific script handling (yes, just UpdatePanels). It might resolve the view problem, but it might also create new and exciting runtime problems.

Comment: Checked the ootb oslo.master found plain ScriptManager: <asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="false" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableScriptGlobalization="false" EnableScriptLocalization="true" />

Comment: You might want to use a masterpage with a SafeScriptManager instead. It's supposed to make UpdatePanels play nice with SharePoint controls. I don't know what the difference is under the hood, but it might make the design view work, since the SafeScriptManager handles conflicting AJAX safely.